# getting error function viewMsg(0) is undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, function

I am getting error

> function viewMsg(0) is undefined

my call to function is like this

```
<A href="javascript:viewMsg('+loan_index+')"> View Message </A>
```

function `viewMsg` is defined on line 1095, however called at line 1843.
Please let me know how to resolve this problem.

Comment: this function is working in fine in IE7 however not working in Mozilla fire fox

Comment: Please provide further code. Quote seems little strange...

Comment: try this `<A href="javascript:viewMsg("+loan_index+")"> View Message </A>` and check for function scope.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it like this:

```
<A href="javascript:viewMsg(loan_index)"> View Message </A>
```

there is no need to put quotes if you want to send a variable value even in the inline javascript calls.

Comment: link opens when I click on view message on IE7. but this doesn't work in Mozilla firefox